# SQL query to pick one image of each id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pick first thumb image of each product (here its entity id)

my query

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
```

but its returning all images i need query to pick 1st image from each id can any help.

[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhYOU.png)

Comment: `SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery LIMIT 1`

Comment: it will limit one product image as a whole i need the images to be limited for each product id seperately

Comment: like [{"product_id":"57","value":"\/s\/s\/ss5-1.jpg"}]

Comment: [{"product_id":"58","value":"\/s\/s\/ss5-2.jpg"}]

Comment: the thing is i dnt know how to limit product id continusely @Niranjan N Raju

Comment: @VigneshPrasanna does this code works for you or not? `SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery 
GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY entity_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery GROUP BY entity_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the returning rows starting from 0 index having limit to 1 record.

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery GROUP BY entity_id
```

Comment: OP need to get **one image from each ID**

Answer (score 1):

try this, use GROUP BY for grouping and order them for getting the first one

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY entity_id
```

Answer (score 1):

you van use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery 
GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY entity_id
```

> `ORDER BY` entity_id fetch the first thumb image

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY `value_id` ASC
```

> When you are doing **`GROUP BY`** you are grouping all the similar
>   product_id or entity_id to one & as you are **`ORDER BY`** value_id by
>   ascending the first inserted row will be at top and grouped by

Check this two links for more details http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp & http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp